# Primefaces p:carousel vertical scrolling

Tags: jsf, primefaces, carousel, vertical-scrolling

I'm using the following code to create a carousel with vertical scrolling. The scroll is working fine as I specified in every 5s is scrolling. I want to make the carousel to scroll vertically. I tried to set the vertical to true or false but the same result. The carousel should be inside of a panel, or some other tag?

I'm using primefaces 5.3. The carousel is working on this version?

```
<p:carousel value="#{exampleBean.cars}" var="car"
    style="width:100%;height:60px;" numVisible="1" cricular="true"
    autoPlayInterval="500" effectDuration="5000" vertical="false">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <h:outputText value="Text:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:carousel>
```

Somebody can help me to get this working?
Thanks.

Comment: This is a known bug in version 5.3  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1107

Comment: Thanks. I changed the primefaces version to 5.2, and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in version 5.3

http://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1107